# Can't change textBox.text in form from other classes - C# - VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a form called Form1. In it, I have a button called Encrypt. When I hit that button I invoke a method in a different class. I want that method to change the value of textBox1.text but nothing happens when I use this code

## in Form1 class

```
public string txtbox1
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

## in a method in the other class

```
Form1 textboxes = new Form1();//creating object of the Form1 class
        textboxes.txtbox1= "whatever";
```

Nothing changes in the first text box. It's like I don't press anything at all!!!

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: What is the definition of the method that you are calling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your other class, you need a reference to the Form on which the button was clicked (and that has your existing text-boxes), not a *new* form.

This new form you're instantiating isn't the one that you're looking at on the screen where you clicked your button.

(I'm assuming your event handler exists within the Form1 class, and that it then "forwards" information out to other class's method as required?  If not... it should!)

The button reference will be obtainable through the `sender` object and the `event args` passed to your event handler.  You can pass a reference to the current `Form1` instance by passing the `this` keyword to your other class's method. Or you could pass the `sender` if that's useful to you, or just pass an explicit reference to the specific text box through to your other method.

eg, to pass a reference to the form to your other method:

```
// Event handler on your form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonWasPressedOnForm(this);   
}

// Other method in your other class
public void ButtonWasPressedOnForm(Form formWhereButtonPressed)
{
    // To act on the text box directly:
    TextBox textBoxToUpdate = (TextBox)formWhereButtonPressed.Controls.Find("textBox1");
    textBoxToUpdate.Text = "whatever";

    // Or, using the Form1.txtBox1 property.
    formWhereButtonPressed.txtBox1 = "whatever";  
}
```

eg, to pass a reference to explicit text box to your other method:

```
// Event handler on your form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonWasPressedOnForm(textBox1);   
}

// Other method in your other class
public void ButtonWasPressedOnForm(TextBox textBoxToUpdate)
{
    textBoxToUpdate.Text = "whatever";
}
```

eg, to pass the event object to your other method:

```
// Event handler on your form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    ButtonWasPressedOnForm(clickedButton);  
}

// Other method in your other class
public void ButtonWasPressedOnForm(Button clickedButton)
{
    Form theParentForm = clickedButton.FindForm();

    // To act on the text box directly:
    TextBox textBoxToUpdate = (TextBox)theParentForm.Controls.Find("textBox1");
    textBoxToUpdate.Text = "whatever";

    // Or, To act on the text box, via the form's property:
    theParentForm.txtBox1 = "whatever";
}
```

Also, stick a break point on your "other method" to ensure this code is even being fired.  If not, go back to your event-handler, ensure that's being fired.  If not, check your event wire-up.

---

Although in all cases you need to be careful of the protection level on the control you want to update... you'll need to make it public, internal, or protected depending on the relationship between your form and the other class, if you want to update it from outside your `Form1` class.

A better OO approach would be to have a method on `Form1` that allows other classes to tell `Form1` to update the control for them (eg `updateTextBox(string newText)`).  Because it's not OO best-practice allow external objects to act on the members of your classes directly (as this requires knowledge of the internal structure of your class... which should be encapsulated so that your implementation can change without breaking the interface that exists between your class and the outside world).

**EDIT:**
Actually, on re-reading your question, you do already encapsulate your text boxes using get/set properties.  Nice.  So you should pass the reference to your Form to your other method, and then update the form's text via the property.  Have added this method to the examples above.

Comment: Thanks mate! That makes sense! But when I pass sender and event args. How can I use them to edit the textbox's text? Could you give me an example of the code in the other class ?

Comment: @RonaDona my pleasure.  Have added some examples.  Pulled from out of my head so can't vouch for the syntax... but you'll get the idea that there's a few different ways to skin the cat ;-)  Just pick the one that makes the most sense to you depending on how you need to use the information in the other class.

Comment: Legend!!! I used the first one. Worked and I am moving to the next step after getting stuck for a couple of hours. Thanks a lot again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @RonaDona Hi again, realised you'd already encapsulated your text boxes with properties, so have added some extra info to the examples, as you really should use that mechanism instead.  You're welcome, and thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 3):

I foud an easy way to do this.
First Creat a TextBox in your Class

```
class class1
   {
   public static TextBox txt1=new TextBox();
   public static void Hello()
     {
      txt1.Text="Hello";
     }
   }
```

There is a button(button1) and a TextBox(textBox1) on form1.
ok,now Copy the address of Your Desired TextBox Must be changed
I tested it,it work properly

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 public Form1()
    {
     InitializeComponent();  
    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      class1.txt1=textBox1;
      class1.Hello();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, what protection level is the Form1 class? That's where I often have issues... I forget that if the class isn't public, it can't be accessed by classes outside of it. "Protected" could also be usable, but it depends on what the relationship is between the two classes.

Comment: +1 A good point worth making.  By _default_ `Form`s are _explicitly_ defined as `public` (at least, in Visual Studio generated code they are).  Which is different to `class`es generally, whose protection levels are not explicitly declared (automatically by VS) and are hence implicitly `internal` for un-nested classes, or `private` if the class is nested within another class.  But if no access modifier is explicitly applied, then a class inheriting from `Form` will behave just like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

i found in situations like this passing information from 1 form to another is to hold the information in a class file not the form its self

example
Form 1:

```
public partial class customerHistory : Form
{
    private string passtexboxvaluetoclass = "";   


    // load class dependant.cs
    dependents cls_dependents = new dependents();

    public customerHistory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dependents.passtexboxvaluetoclass = textbox1.text;
        // load next form
    }
```

then all i would do is on the 2nd form just call on form_load

```
label1.text = dependents.passtexboxvaluetoclass;
```

this way you can call back mass ammounts of information as they will all be stored within the class and not the phyical form itself

Comment: But your `dependants` is instantiated as a _member_ of  `customerHistory:Form`, so you can't access `dependants` independently from `customerHistory` anyhow.  Did you mean to instantiate this new class as a peer to `customerHistory`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by creating event in your class and your form subscribe to that event and pass data to be updated to UI as `EventArgs`...