# How to access text button outside Form.cs class (I mean in Program.cs)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created  a Form in c# windows. My form contains a button and a text box and it 's name is **textbox2** here and it contains  code like this in **Form1.Designer.cs** :

```
this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(683, 14);
this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
this.textBox2.TabIndex = 22;
```

Now i have created another class called Programss.cs which will do some task and as the task finished i want to print on my form something like this:

```
textBox2.txt= "Task finished"; //it should print on the textbox of my Form1.cs
```

**How to access this textBox2(which can only be accessed currently in Form1.Designer.cs) in Programss.cs and my other classes ?**

EDIT: After Philip Stuyck's comments:
Here is my Form1.cs code :

```
namespace S
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
         //please see here
        public string TextMessage
        {
            get { return textBox3.Text; }
            set { textBox3.Text = value; }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
          //  StartServer();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And Program.cs is :

```
 namespace Senter code here
    {
         class Program 
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //    OtherImportantClasses.Programs prgms = new OtherImportantClasses.Programs();
                Form1 theForm = new Form1();
                theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
            }
        }
    }
```

Form1.Designer.cs is:

```
namespace Shekhar
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtPort = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnClose
            // 
            this.btnClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 11);
            this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
            this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnClose.TabIndex = 21;
            this.btnClose.Text = "Close";
            this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
            // 
            // btnStart
            // 
            this.btnStart.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(227, 12);
            this.btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
            this.btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnStart.TabIndex = 20;
            this.btnStart.Text = "Start";
            this.btnStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStart_Click);
            // 
            // txtPort
            // 
            this.txtPort.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 12);
            this.txtPort.Name = "txtPort";
            this.txtPort.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 20);
            this.txtPort.TabIndex = 19;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 12);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 18);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 18;
            this.label1.Text = "Port : ";
            OtherImportantClasses.Programs prog = new OtherImportantClasses.Programs();


            //
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 20);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 18);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 18;
            this.label2.Text = "Total Number of device connected :";
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(683, 14);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 22;
         //   this.textBox2.Text = "testbox2";
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 60);
            this.textBox3.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
            this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(702, 243);
            this.textBox3.TabIndex = 23;


            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(818, 315);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtPort);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Shekhar\'s GT06";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        /*
        public string TextMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox2.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox2.Text = value;
            }
        }
        */
        #endregion



        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStart;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPort;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
    }
}
Form1.Designer.cs is :

    namespace S`enter code here`
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            public void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.txtPort = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // btnClose
                // 
                this.btnClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 11);
                this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
                this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                this.btnClose.TabIndex = 21;
                this.btnClose.Text = "Close";
                this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
                // 
                // btnStart
                // 
                this.btnStart.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(227, 12);
                this.btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
                this.btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                this.btnStart.TabIndex = 20;
                this.btnStart.Text = "Start";
                this.btnStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStart_Click);
                // 
                // txtPort
                // 
                this.txtPort.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 12);
                this.txtPort.Name = "txtPort";
                this.txtPort.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 20);
                this.txtPort.TabIndex = 19;
                // 
                // label1
                // 
                this.label1.AutoSize = true;
                this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 12);
                this.label1.Name = "label1";
                this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 18);
                this.label1.TabIndex = 18;
                this.label1.Text = "Port : ";
                OtherImportantClasses.Programs prog = new OtherImportantClasses.Programs();


                //
                // label2
                // 
                this.label2.AutoSize = true;
                this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 20);
                this.label2.Name = "label2";
                this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 18);
                this.label2.TabIndex = 18;
                this.label2.Text = "Total Number of device connected :";
                // 
                // textBox2
                // 
                this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(683, 14);
                this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
                this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                this.textBox2.TabIndex = 22;
             //   this.textBox2.Text = "testbox2";
                // 
                // textBox3
                // 
                this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 60);
                this.textBox3.Multiline = true;
                this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
                this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(702, 243);
                this.textBox3.TabIndex = 23;


                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(818, 315);
                this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
                this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
                this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
                this.Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
                this.Controls.Add(this.txtPort);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Shekhar\'s GT06";
                this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.PerformLayout();

            }

            /*
            public string TextMessage
            {
                get
                {
                    return textBox2.Text;
                }
                set
                {
                    textBox2.Text = value;
                }
            }
            */
            #endregion



            private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStart;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPort;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
        }
    }
```

**It dont give any error but it do not print anything in textBox3** .

NOTE: Please note that first i run the winform code i click a button and when i click the button some proccess will run which will further print the text in the textbox. (I feel like my textmessage is not intialized by my message passed to it).

Comment: Your code will not work because Form1 theForm = new Form1();
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished"; is never executed. Application.Run(new Form1());  returns only when the form is closed.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck so what can be done to achieve the target ?

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Thanks for the answer. I have one question about your answer. If i create another class ..lets say "test.cs" and i write your code there ? will it work ? (I mean soemthing liek this in test.cs :Form1 theForm = new Form1();
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
Application.Run(theForm); )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that textBox2 is public.(can be done in the designer)
Keep a reference to Form1 when you create it and access textBox2 via that reference.

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();
... //do stuff
theForm.textBox2.Text = "Task finished";
```

This is not the most elegant approach to this, but it should work.
An alternative is like this :

```
public partial class Form1{
   public string TextMessage{
        get{
            return textBox2.Text;
        }
        set{
            textBox2.Text = value;
        }
   }
}
```

and in program.cs

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();
... //do stuff
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
```

your code will not work because

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
```

is never executed.

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

returns only when the form is closed and then the application will end.

Following will work:

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
Application.Run(theForm);
```

But I have the feeling you don't quite understand the framework.
Application.run, will make your application enter into a message loop which makes the application receive window messages.

Comment: If this does not work, then show your program.cs and Form code.

Comment: Please note that first i run the winform code i click a button and when i click the button some proccess will run which will further print the text in the textbox. (I feel like my textmessage is not intialized by my message passed to it).

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to have a method accessible in your Form1 that sets the textBox name to whatever you want. For instance:

```
public static void SetText (string message)
{
     TextBox2.Text = message;
}
```

You would then call this from your Program.cs class:

```
Form1.SetText("Whatever text you want the text on the Form1 - TextBox2 to say");
```

This is the poor man's way of changing the text. There is a more detailed explanation [on this other post if you need more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879181/cant-change-textbox-text-in-form-from-other-classes-c-sharp-vs-2010)

Comment: a static method SetText will not work, because textBox2 is an instance variable of the form and you therefore don't have access to it.

Comment: @Ryan i tried your way but i really have no access to TextBox2 in Form1.cs inside function SetText(..)

Comment: Because textBox2 is an instance variable, and the method is static. Your compiler will tell you this as well.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I tried your way also but please see what i got http://prntscr.com/65po2b

Comment: I don't have access to that link. and updated a mistake in my code as well. TextMessage is a string and I forgot to declare TextMessage as a string.

Comment: @kalho The reason that you got that error is that you didn't set the SetText method to static. The way that you posted also works, however, you would have been able to reference it with the static call.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to print end result on textBox2.txt textbox, right? So you want to execute some methods on Programss.cs and once execution is finished you want to show "Task finished" on textBox2.txt.

If I am not wrong, what you have to do is return a value from a method from Programss.cs class. You have to call this method from  Form1.Designer.cs class. Based on return value you can do whatever you want.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two separate forms, setting text on the second, and expecting it to appear on the first.

Do this:

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();
theForm.TextMessage = "Task finished";
Application.Run(theForm);
```

Comment: I am not creating to separate forms .Its just 1 form that contain gui. But i have another class Programs.cs which should render in the textbox "Task Finished" after some task is finished (dynamically).

Comment: That makes no sense at all.  Your original code popped an instance of `Form1` on startup.  Then attempted to create a 2nd instance of the same form class, only this time with the text set.  So you want the form to open once without text, then open again with it?  Perhaps you should be more clear as to your goal, because as of now it makes little sense.

Comment: Ok so please read it : I have a form1 pop up at starting. which will display the data received on textblock through another class (Not from Form1.cs.. let say test.cs). The problem is the form is launched at startup and the data received is not updated on textbox. To update the dynamically got data on Form1 by  doinf again Application.Run(theForm);